# Find all continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f(x))^2+8=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Find all continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$(f(x))^2+8=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$$

If I set $F(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$ then $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$,

so $(f(x))^2+8$ is diferentible as it does $\sqrt{F(x)-8}=|f(x)|$,

and then $F'(x)=(|f(x)|^2+8)'=2|f(x)||f(x)|'=f(x)$.

and then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ fails as we are asking that $f(0)^2+8=8=\int_0^0 0 \; dt=0$ which fails.

Comment: Can you use my comment to prove that there are no $f(x)$ that satisfy the requirement?  If so, you could post it as an answer

Comment: Ho, I see $f(0)^2=-8$

Comment: If $f$ real valued?

Comment: That is right and if $f$ is real you are done.

Comment: and what about if $f$ is a complex fuction?

Comment: As seen above, there is no continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies this equation. If $f$ is complex-valued, you need to claryfy what the integral means.

Comment: If $f(x) \neq 0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I downvoted you because your answer was wrong and I was trying to explain to you why your answer was unhelpful (even wrong). If you don't want downvotes, don't post wrong answers. As I was saying, the function $f(x)=|x|$ shows that continuity of $f$ and differentiability of $f^2$ does NOT imply differentiability of $f$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Unfortunately there is an element on this site that likes to downvote for the slightest thing without allowing some time for repair.

Comment: @Dr.MV I agree that $\frac{x}{2}+C$ solves the equation, but the question was to find ALL continuous functions, and you didn't show that those were the ONLY ones. Clearly the OP was having issues with the differentiability of $f$, that's the entire point of this question. Not addressing that is not answering OPs question. Even if you could show that $f$ had to be differentiable, unless you actually showed that your answer was unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(f(0))^2+8=\int\limits_0^0f(t)dt=0\Rightarrow(f(0))^2=-8$$ which is a contradiction since $f$ is real valued.